# DeviceConnectionChangeTrigger - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm developing an UWP app for Desktop and Mobile. I'd like using DeviceConnectionChangeTrigger to identify when my BT device is in range, but when i try using it, I cannot register background task cause it keeps return System.ArgumentException "Value does not fall within the expected range." when executing "Register" method of BackgroundTaskBuilder.

code is very simple

```
    var current = BackgroundExecutionManager.GetAccessStatus();
    if (current == BackgroundAccessStatus.Unspecified || current == BackgroundAccessStatus.Denied)
    {
      var result = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
      if (result == BackgroundAccessStatus.Denied || result == BackgroundAccessStatus.Unspecified)
        throw new Exception("You cannot register Access");
    }

    //I tested it with BT and BTLE device but no luck
    //var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelector());
    var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector());
    var device = devices.FirstOrDefault();
    if (device == null) throw new Exception("Device not found");

    var trigger = await DeviceConnectionChangeTrigger.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
    //trigger.MaintainConnection = true;

    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
    {
      Name = "BluetoothConnectionWatcher",
      TaskEntryPoint = typeof(BluetoothConnectionWatcherTask).FullName
    };
    builder.SetTrigger(trigger);

    //error on next line!
    var r = builder.Register();
```

My project has Bluetooth capabilities and one background task registered with Bluetooth property flagged.

All Bluetooth functionalities work well and I can communicate with devices without problem.

I tried several BT and BTLE device and for all of them seems I have the same problem.

I tried on Desktop and Mobile version of Windows 10 (both last fast insider build). Same problem.

The device.Id returned by code is similar to "Bluetooth#Bluetooth00:1a:7d:da:71:0a-fc:58:fa:4c:17:0a" for every BT device i tried (of course 2nd MAC address change based on device...)

Any advice?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, with BLE you should use the Triggers designed for it. Thus if it is characteristics change you would want to get knowledge about, then you should use [GattCharacteristicNotificationTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.applicationmodel.background.gattcharacteristicnotificationtrigger.gattcharacteristicnotificationtrigger), and example on using it can be found from [my blog](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=167).

Then if it just BLE device availability, and you can detect yours via scanrecord data, then do use the [BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.background.bluetoothleadvertisementwatchertrigger.aspx) instead. My Friend Juhana has example fro this in [his blog](http://juhana.cloudapp.net/?p=89).

Comment: Thanks for links! I'm watching at them right now... I'll let you know

Comment: 2nd link does not woks, do you have alternative one?

Comment: It appears to be inaccessible at this point of time, worked fine when I added the link, assuming it to be online shorty again.